# Salesforce Control v's Treatment

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, journeybuilder

I would like to know if / how I can apply a control cell in Salesforce Marketing Cloud and have it log to a contact history as a control?

I know that I can create a split e.g. 10/90 and delivery my 90% volume as a campaign. But I would like to flag the other 10% as a control group so I can compare their activity against those who received the campaign.

I would need it flagging as a control so I know who were the people in control so that I can do a direct comparison for campaign evaluation. I know this can be done in Unica and Adobe but need to find a way of completing this in Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well the scenario, there is a specific feature in Marketing Cloud that may help you to build and track these control groups vs the rest of the audience. It is called [A/B Testing](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_ab_testing.htm&type=5) and it works similarly like the approach you shared using Split Activities in Journey Builder.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are you able to track those selected for A/B testing post campaign? For example be clear on the ID's of those selected for A and B?

Comment: Yes, in the tracking tab. And in the A/B Test Summary report you can check also the results.